# How can I enable framebuffer in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, framebuffer

How can I enable framebuffer in Debian console?

This is what I've already tried:

- Add the following lines to the "/etc/default/grub" file:

  GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768

  GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768

The following line is commented out

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

- I've also add "set gfxpayload=keep" line below "set gfxmode={$GRUB_GFXMODE}" in the "/etc/grub.d/00_header" file.
- Execute "update-grub"

Nothing happens. I switched to the second virtual console (Ctrl-Alt-2) and tried to execute the following command:

```
~ $ fbi some_image.jpg
using "DejaVu Sans Mono-16", pixelsize=16.67 file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you reboot? GRUB only sets these settings at boot time.

Comment: @Graeme I've thought that "update-grub" command do this. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope, the `update-grub` command definitely does not reboot your system.

Comment: The `update-grub` script just updates the files in `/boot` using e.g. `/etc/default/grub`. It does not reboot your system.

Comment: @Graeme Nope, I've thought that this command eliminates the need of reboot

Comment: Definitely not, GRUB can only apply settings to the kernel at boot time. `update-grub` just updates the files that it reads at boot time. GRUB stands for Grand Unified *Bootloader*, it doesn't do anything while your system is running.

Comment: Ok, I've restarted my system and now it works in virtual console. Can I use framebuffer in the terminal emulators too?

Comment: That's a no too, the framebuffer is for the Linux Console only. If you want to change the way your terminal emulator displays, then change it settings.

Comment: @Graeme Can you tell me which settings should I change for this? I'm using xterm right now

Comment: Note that support for this has to be built into the kernel.  You might want to check your `/proc/config.gz`.

Comment: Configuring `xterm` is tricky, there are a few different files that could be used `~/.Xresources`, `~/.xsessionrc` `~/.Xdefaults` depending on distro. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Here is a link on configuring `xterm` - http://unix4lyfe.org/xterm/ - if you don't find what you are looking for then you should post a different question.

Comment: I need to enable framebuffer support in xterm, not the general manual about xterm's config